# Very slow wakeup from locked screen

Tags: release-juno, lock

My elementary 5.0 is extremely slow to wake up from locked screen after it's been locked for a while. I input my password and then nothing happens for a long time. We're talking minutes. How would I go about troubleshooting this?

And BTW, I've done [this](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/89#issuecomment-461169400) to keep it from suspending when on power. Maybe that broke something?

EDIT: I'm using a SSD, and I have set the computer to never suspend. There was a workaround I had to do as there is a known bug in the power settings, see the link above.

Comment: i just installed elementary OS 5.1 Hera on my core-i7/ 16G RAM, 256GB static HDD laptop and agree that this OS is extremely slow in every aspect. It just does not respond and we need to wait loooong even for small clicks.

Comment: it is better if you upgrade your system and upgrade the kernel?

Comment: I really want some position about this topic of Elementary OS 5.0 and 5.1 being so slow at any circumstances. My configurations are almost the same as @dakshinamurthy and it keeps slow. The only thing I can think of is that is not recognizing my onboard GPU.

Comment: Same with 6.0 with laptop set to never sleep. A

Answer (score 0):

are you running a spinning disk or SSD ?

normally when a machine comes back from sleep (hibernation) it needs to read all the data that was saved to disk before you can have any KB input or the system works properly.

this same happens on PC and MAC if they go into hibernation.

hibernation is different to lets say screen off for example.

are able to provide more information on your setup specifically the HDD type and computer brand, MB type etc could also help.

are you using provider supplied drivers?

i would also recommend turning off "suspend" mode.

applications > power > suspend > never.

personally i'm not seeing this issue running with a VMware fusion VM.

for me the system suspends and then returns straight away.

this could come down to the standardised drivers for virtual machines etc + on SSD drive.

hopefully i can be of more assistance with additional info.

""Cheers
G

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I have SSD and the system **should** never suspend. I haven't done anything to my drivers.